# Export footprints of an unmanaged raster catalog with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase

Is there a way to access the "export footprints" function for an unmanaged raster catalog with arcpy? It can be done through ArcMap when a raster catalog is added to the map as seen below.

[image: Export footprints from the GUI]

The context is that I am working on a python script to automate the process of adding rasters to an unmanaged catalog, and then exporting the footprints. The raster catalog is in a file geodatabase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe little modification to this:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy, traceback, os, sys
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

try:
    # input folder with shapefiles or rasters
    inputFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    env.workspace = inputFolder
    # output folder for tiles shapefile
    outputFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    # output shapefile name
    outputFile = "tiles.shp"
    theType=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

    if theType=='Shapefile':
        inRasters = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    elif theType=='Raster':
        inRasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
    arcpy.AddMessage(len(inRasters))

    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outputFolder, outputFile, "POLYGON", "", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", "", "", "0", "0", "0")
    outputFile=outputFolder+ os.sep +outputFile
    arcpy.AddField_management(outputFile, "FILE_NAME", "TEXT", "", "", 250, "", "NON_NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

    inRows = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputFile,("Shape@","FILE_NAME"))
    arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "", 0, len(inRasters))
    for inRaster in inRasters:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(inRaster)
        ext=desc.extent
        thePoints=arcpy.Array([ext.lowerLeft, ext.upperLeft,ext.upperRight,ext.lowerRight])
        polygon = arcpy.Polygon(thePoints)
        inRows.insertRow((polygon,inputFolder+os.sep+inRaster))
        arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()
        arcpy.AddMessage (inRaster + "...processed")

    del inRows
except:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n    " + \
            str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
    msgs = "GEOPROCESSOR ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)
    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
```

[image]

Will get you there

Comment: Thanks @FelixIP, I will try this out and let you know how it works.

Comment: This does work, but it I found it simpler to use copy features on the raster catalog, and it creates a polygon feature class with the footprints.