# Creating fishnet grid polygon layer from set of ortho rasters in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, vector-grid, orthophoto

I have a set of ortho slides (SID format) for my city. The slides do not overlap, and cover the entire city and immediate environs. What I want to do is create a grid-like polygon layer with separate polygons for each raster slide. All are equal in size (6k feet by 4k feet), so I would assume that this would involve creating a fishnet, right? The problem I am encountering is how to create the polygon in the first place. Would I create a larger polygon that would encase all the slides, and then create the fishnet from there?

Working with ArcMap Desktop v10.3.

Comment: The [Create Fishnet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm) tool only really requires a starting point and a second point to determine the Y-axis (and, implicitly, the X-axis, orthogonal to Y; see the [doc](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/how-create-fishnet-works.htm) for details) , but wouldn't be appropriate if there's any overlap.  In that case you could just assemble polygons from the image corners in a DA InsertCursor.

Comment: You might try Gdalindex. This free command line tool will create a Shapefile with a Polygon for each image in a folder. Each polygon will contain the original image name and extent. There are other options to the tool.

Comment: I don't think it is a fishnet you are after, it is more like a footprints feature class that you need to create.  Ignoring the bookmark part, much of the code you will need to do that can be found in ListBookmarks example 3 at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listbookmarks.htm

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181199/export-footprints-of-an-unmanaged-raster-catalog-with-arcpy

Comment: Create new raster mosaic dataset in FGDB. Add your rasters, right click on footprint - data - export

Comment: @FelixIP That sounds very promising - I think you should write up an answer with some slightly more detailed steps.

Answer (score 1):

Create mxd and set projection the same as your images.

Create file geodatabase somewhere, preferably on hard drive using arccatalog window.

Right click and create new mosaic dataset, 3 bands, same projection.

Right click on dataset, add rasters. No thumbnails.

You'll find mosaic dataset added to table of content. Right click on footprints, data, export will ask you for output polygons layer.

This is scripting free approach.